# PHP não imprime resultado quando igual a 0

Tags: php

Todos os resultados são impressos na tela exceto quando é `0` e eu preciso que o número `0` seja impresso. Se é `NULL` ele satisfaz a condição abaixo e imprime corretamente o hífen.

```
if($dados['dado_1']===null){
  echo "<td width='11%' style='text-align:center;'><p><br/>-</p></td>";
}else{
  echo "<td width='11%' style='text-align:center;><p><br/>".$dados['dado_1']."</p></td>";
}
```

Comment: essa verificação `===` é somente para dadoos `BOOLEAN`, com `null` não funcionará.

Comment: Opa, valeu, bom saber. Mas mesmo trocando para == não resolve o problema.

Comment: Os dados são do tipo inteiro?

Comment: Não, são do tipo FLOAT

Answer (score 2):

O mais correto nesse caso é você usar o `is_null`, porque quando o valor da variável for 0 retornará **falso**, portanto não cairá no primeiro `IF`. Minha sugestão de código:

```
if(is_null($dados['dado_1'])){
  echo "<td width='11%' style='text-align:center;'><p><br/>-</p></td>";
}else{
  echo "<td width='11%' style='text-align:center;><p><br/>".(string)$dados['dado_1']."</p></td>";
}
```

Comment: Beleza! Vou trocar para is_null, mas de qualquer modo, mesmo trocando para is_null continua sem exibir o resultando quando é '0'

Comment: Você tem então que indicar que é uma string. Estou alterando a resposta para você ver como faz.

Comment: ainda assim não exibe quando o valor é igual a 0

Answer (score 1):

Ele deve tá vindo vazio, coloca assim:

```
echo "<td width='11%' style='text-align:center;><p><br/>". $dados['dado_1'] ? $dados['dado_1'] : '0' ."</p></td>";
```

Comment: Opa meu caro, tendei do jeito que você falou mas continuou sem funcionar. Não houve alteração no resultado. Mas de qualquer modo, poderia me explicar essa sintaxe?

Comment: Essa sintaxe é um "if inline", basicamente eu estou checando se o $dados['dados_1'] tem valor verdadeiro, se sim ele coloca o próprio valor, se não coloca '0'. você já tentou dar um `var_dump` em `$dados['dado_1']` quando ele vem 0?

Comment: no var_dump todos os resultados são exibidos inclusive os que tem o valor igual a 0